# Question about projection map in short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

[image]

In an short exact sequences, like the one appear in the indentation and the one appear in the included screenshot:

> $\{0\}\stackrel{\rm f_{i-1}}{\longrightarrow}A\stackrel{\rm f_{i}}{\longrightarrow}B\stackrel{\rm f_{i+1}}{\longrightarrow}C\stackrel{\rm f_{i+2}}{\longrightarrow}\{0\}$

where $\text{Im }f_{i-1} = \text{Ker }f_{i}$.

I understand why the $f_{i+1}$ map is a surjective map, since $\text{Ker}f_{i+1}=C$.  But according to here, $\pi$, $\iota$ in place of $f_{i+1}$, $f_{i}$ respectively and change of letters designating the sets being map to. [Section 1.11 second paragraph pg 79, also included in the screenshot](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JFEyDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&dq=inclusion+map,+one+to+one,+exact+sequence&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ1KSvpNL5AhXAEmIAHYcuBTkQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=inclusion%20map%2C%20one%20to%20one%2C%20exact%20sequence&f=false) also calls it a projection map.  Can someone explain to me in what sense it is a projection map.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Google books doesn't give each viewer the same selection of preview pages, so even though the preview shows you page 79 (presumably), it doesn't show me page 79.

Comment: Your formula contains maps labeled with $f$s, your line right after talks about $g$s...

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem tells you that a surjective group homomorphism $f\colon G\to K$ is essentially "the same" as the canonical projection map $G\to G/\ker(f)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you mean when a homomorphic map between groups can be factor into a surjective (canonical projection) map and an injective homomorphic map, like discussed here in the last paragraph:  https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Abstract_Algebra/e19wEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=canonical+projection+map+and+surjective+homomorphism&pg=PA46-IA50&printsec=frontcover

Comment: When the initial morphism is surjective, the second map in the factorization is an isomorphism, which tells you the image is isomorphic to the quotient, via $g\mathrm{ker}(f) \longmapsto f(g)$.